# Error while adding Picasso library in Android studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, picasso

I was using Eclipse, I had (picasso.jar) in libs folder, then I have generated Gradle build then switch to Android studio. but Picasso library stopped working.

My project structure is like:

```
ProjectStructure--> dependices--> library dependices -->picasso.
```

This is the error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'HomePage'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.squareup:picasso:2.2.+.
>        Required by:
>            :HomePage:unspecified

build.gradle

```
   buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
 }
  apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile project(':libraries:process_library')
 compile 'com.squareup:picasso:2.2.+'
    }

      android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

}

What do I have to do in order to make Picasso Library work again?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Android Studio; it's given you the wrong dependency for Picasso. In your build.gradle, change this line:

```
compile 'com.squareup:picasso:2.2.+'
```

to this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.+'
```

I've filed a bug for this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69509